# Permissions for other user to run script with python package

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pip, gpio, openhab

I have installed a [lib](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_WS2801) via `pip`: `sudo pip install adafruit-ws2801`

Then, I gave it rights: `sudo chmod +x /etc/openhab2/scripts/myscript.py`

However, when I try to start it as another user, an error appears:

```
sudo su -s /bin/bash -c '/etc/openhab2/scripts/myscript.py' openhab
```

This error:

```
...
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/Adafruit_GPIO/SPI.py", line 42, in __init__
    self._device.open(port, device)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

When I start the script as my current user (without sudo), everything is fine. But this user can not access it. Do I need to give more permissions for this user? In the first line of the python file, I wrote `#!/usr/bin/env python3`

Comment: It is not python script permission problem it is some device that script try to access problem. Check device permission for user that run script.

Comment: Permission seems to be denied to `self._device` in the script, not to the script itself.

Comment: usually I have to call scripts that use the Raspberry Pi GPIOs with `sudo`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that the user is not in the right group. So I added it in the specific group (spi) and now it works!